# How to include NULL values as zero to variance calculation in Python?

Tags: python, variance

I have problem calculating variance with "hidden" NULL (zero) values. Usually that shouldn't be a problem because NULL value is not a value but in my case it is essential to include those NULLs as zero to variance calculation. So I have Dataframe that looks like this:

TableA:

```
A   X   Y
1   1   30
1   2   20
2   1   15
2   2   20
2   3   20
3   1   30
3   2   35
```

Then I need to get variance for each different X value and I do this:

```
TableA.groupby(['X']).agg({'Y':'var'})
```

But answer is not what I need since I would need the variance calculation **to include also NULL value Y for X=3 when A=1 and A=3.**

What my dataset should look like to get the needed variance results:

```
A   X   Y
1   1   30
1   2   20
1   3   0
2   1   15
2   2   20
2   3   20
3   1   30
3   2   35
3   3   0
```

So I need variance to take into account that every X should have 1,2 and 3 and when there are no values for Y in certain X number it should be 0. Could you help me in this? How should I change my TableA dataframe to be able to do this or is there another way?

Desired output for TableA should be like this:

```
X   Y
1   75.000000
2   75.000000
3   133.333333
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Approach of below solution is appending not existing sequence with Y=0. Little messy but hope this will help.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

TableA = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,2,2,2,3,3],
             'X':[1,2,1,2,3,1,2],
             'Y':[30,20,15,20,20,30,35]})

TableA['A'] = TableA['A'].astype(int)

#### Create row with non existing sequence and fill with 0  ####

for i in range(1,TableA.X.max()+1):
    for j in TableA.A.unique():
        if not TableA[(TableA.X==i) & (TableA.A==j)]['Y'].values :
            TableA = TableA.append(pd.DataFrame({'A':[j],'X':[i],'Y':[0]}),ignore_index=True)


TableA.groupby('X').agg({'Y':np.var})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It seems promising with the sample data I put there. In my original data it is however pointing out an error 

"'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"

This comes because my A values are floats in original data set and they also are random numbers so for example 33.0, 45.0 and 88.0. How should I change the code to work in those cases as well?

Comment: @maijanen thanks for feedback. now answer is updated check if it works

Comment: Thanks GIRISH kuniyal! I think this might actually work.Just maybe a stupid question of this astype(int): does this mix something if my A:s are let's say 33.4 and 33.8?

Comment: @maijanen yes it will mix, if lets A is float number representation then you can remove astype statement above and get the correct answer for 33.4 and 33.8 too.

Comment: Thanks GIRISH kuniyal I think this works with my data really well although it is a bit complex :)

Answer (score 3):

Compute the variance directly, but divide by the number of different possibilities for A

```
# three in your example. adjust as needed
a_choices = len(TableA['A'].unique())

def variance_with_missing(vals):
    mean_with_missing = np.sum(vals) / a_choices
    ss_present = np.sum((vals - mean_with_missing)**2)
    ss_missing = (a_choices - len(vals)) * mean_with_missing**2
    return (ss_present + ss_missing) / (a_choices - 1)


TableA.groupby(['X']).agg({'Y': variance_with_missing})
```

Comment: above code is giving error NameError: name 'x_choices' is not defined. please provide example x_choices it will surely help

Comment: @GIRISHkuniyal should be obvious what it is, if one reads my answer, but here you go.

Comment: Thanks @BlackBear for adding x_choices but it is not giving output what question author requires.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @BlackBear. However this is not giving the result I need.

Comment: @maijanen yup, fixed it

Comment: @maijanen if you are satisfied with this solution, please [accept my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Comment: @BlackBear thanks! This seems to work great with the sample data I gave but what if there were also other columns than Y that I need the variance? For example if there were Y, B and C in the same situation. Code you provided has only one variance value and the function knows only Y.

Comment: Thanks! This seems really legit but I'm not able to get that to work with the real dataset I have. Variances have only negative values. I don't know the reason. But now I was able to get this to work with @GIRISHkuniyal answer.

Comment: @maijanen just be aware of how poorly that solution scales

Comment: Since I have not coded a lot I don't see the scaling problem there. Could you tell me what the problem is so I'll be able to prepare?

Comment: @maijanen repeated scanning of the dataframe, as well as creation of potentially a lot of new dataframes. With 5k random rows, the difference is 10 seconds versus 10 _milli_ seconds (four orders of magnitude), and it will be much worse if you have more rows.

Comment: @BlackBear upvote from my side for your amazing solution. I learn new different direction of approaching same problem.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I try to get this working also with your solution once more since it would be better code. But my data has only like 2k rows so GIRISH's solution works also here.

Comment: @maijanen up to you. If you update your question with an example of where this fails I will try to fix it